# How do I pass a method with my own constraints in a controller that uses request pattern to display data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request

Merry Christmass team!
I have a problem trying to figure out how to pass a method with my own constraints in a controller that is bound to request patter paradigm:

**Sample Controller Code:**

```
class SampleController
{
    protected $model = SampleModel::class;
    protected $indexRequest = IndexRequest::class;
 
}
```

**Request Class**

```
class IndexRequest extends FormRequest
{

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */

    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [];
    }
```

Assume I have a method that I want to do something different.Say I want to fetch some data based on some column constraints.
Whats the approach?

Comment: Depends on what you want to do. "how to pass a method with my own constraints..." Will this method determine whether the request will be "cancelled"?

Comment: @Christian
I want to fetch data with applied constraints on the query.The     protected $indexRequest = IndexRequest::class;
does fetch data from the database but int brings everything.

Comment: So your question boils down to, how to only query certain data from the database depending on HTTP request? Is that correct?

Comment: @Christian yes thats my question